# Make an HTML checkbox remain checked unless unchecked

Tags: php, html, forms

How do you make an HTML checkbox to remain checked (when a user checks it) after the form has been processed by a PHP script and similarly remain unchecked if the user revisits the form and makes it unchecked.

Comment: By setting its `checked` attribute appropriately from PHP when generating the HTML.

Comment: you need to store the user choice somewhere and then on the form page based on the saved value choose to set or not the `checked` attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this. `myCheckbox` can be whatever you want.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="myCheckbox" <?php if ($_REQUEST['myCheckbox']) echo 'checked'; ?>>
```